# Flatten JSON like data in Postgres 11 Database

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following data in a Postgres table that I need to flatten out:

```
data
===============================================================================================
{"Exterior Lights" :["Headlights - Forward Adaptive","Headlights - Laser","Headlights - LED"]}
{"Generic" : ["Launch Control"]} 
{"Mirror" :["Blind Spot Assistant","Door Mirrors - Integrated LED"]}
{"Safety" :["Tyre Pressure Monitoring", "ABS"]}
```

Ideally the above data it would look like this afterwards:

```
System                             Type
=======                            ====
Exterior Lights                    Headlights - Forward Adaptive
Exterior Lights                    Headlights - Laser
Exterior Lights                    headlights - LED
Generic                            Launch Control
Mirror                             Blind Spot Assistant
Mirror                             Door Mirror - Integrated LED
Safety                             Tyre Pressure Monitor 
Safety                             ABS
```

I've tried various combinations of JSON operators but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first extract the key/value pairs as rows which can be done using `jsonb_each()`. Then you can use `jsonb_array_elements_text()` to create a row for each array element:

```
select x.system, u.type
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each(t.data) as x(system, value)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(x.value) as u(type);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5cc1b8867e6737a21efc18375c95aa6e)